# Probability of union of discrete events vs intersection of discrete events

Tags: probability

In the book shown in the link below,p36 section 2.1.3.

https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html

The author defines the probability of the conjunction of two events as:

$Pr(A ∧ B) = Pr(A, B) (1)$

If A and B are independent events, we have

$Pr(A, B) = Pr(A) Pr(B) (2)$

the author then gives the following example:

> For example, suppose X and Y are chosen uniformly at random from the
> set $\chi = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Let A be the event that $X ∈ \{1, 2 \}$, and B be the
> event that $Y ∈ \{3\}$. Then we have $Pr(A, B) = Pr(A) Pr(B) = \frac{1}{2}·\frac{1}{4}$.

The author then defines the probability of the union of two events as:

$Pr(A ∨ B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) − Pr(A ∧ B) (3)$

If the events are mutually exclusive (so they cannot happen at the same time), we get:

$Pr(A ∨ B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) (4)$

The author then gives another example

> For example, suppose X is chosen uniformly at random from the set
> $\chi = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Let A be the event that $X ∈ \{1, 2 \}$ and B be
> the event that $X ∈ {3}$. Then we have $Pr(A ∨ B) = \frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$.

- How can the same disjoint events be independent in the first example but not the second?

  - Thus according to equation 3 the union should be    $\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{4} -
       \frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{4}$ why is this intersection not subtracted from
    the sum? (Even if the events were not independent the intersection
    would still be defined and should
    still be subtracted according to equation 3)
- This is of course based on the assumption that the intersection is
  defined to be the same thing in both examples.

  - One case where the intersection would not be the same would be the case of events happening in sequence rather than in parallel. If they happen in parallel and are disjoint then Y occurring means that X has not occurred and therefore $Pr(X) = 0$. In the sequence case then the fact that you for Y = {3} on the first go does no change the probability that you get X or Y on the second throw.
  - Is this the only way that both examples above can be valid?
- How to express this simultaneous vs sequential distinction in equation 2 though?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Not sure I see the question here.  Are you suggesting that there is some problem with one or more of the examples you describe?  There are, of course, situations in which two events are neither independent nor mutually exclusive.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: In your 1st example $A,B$ are independent. In the 2nd one they are not, and $Pr(A ∧ B) =Pr(B|A)Pr(A)=0\cdot Pr(A)=0\ne\frac12\cdot\frac14.$

Comment: Both examples are based on the same events so how can the same events be independent in the first example but not the second?

Comment: I have tried editing the question is that clearer now?

Comment: The examples do not involve the same events.  In the first, the events are "$X$ is either $1$ or $2$" and "$Y$ is $3$".  In the second example the events are "$X$ is either $1$ or $2$" and "$X$ is $3$".

Comment: @lulu Should the second example be  "X  is either 1 or 2 " or "X is 3"?

Comment: That's what you wrote.  And as the intent was to illustrate the notion of Mutually Exclusive events, that would be a good example.  Clearly we can't have both of those happening at once.  Whereas, in the first example, it was perfectly possible to have both at once.

Comment: To stress:  I was just describing the two events, not talking about the union or the intersection of them.  In the second example, the intersection is empty (as the events are mutually exclusive) and the union is the event "$X$ is one of $1,2,3$".